# What does this image represent and how to sketch it?

Tags: geometry, functions, graphing-functions

I saw this question on a mathematics telegram channel:

> What does this image represent and how we can sketch it with
> mathematical functions or mathematical equations?

[image]

I'm not sure what this image is about and not sure what different colors mean here. I see a square divided into for equal squares. and there are lots of shapes like circle but most of them aren't really a circle.
Maybe it is about some advanced fields in mathematics?

Comment: Could be field lines of some sort, but it's hard to guess without any context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After playing around a little, I'm pretty sure that it's a [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) plot of the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}
,\qquad
z \in \mathbf{C}
,
$$
with zeros at $z=\pm 1$ and poles at $z=\pm i$.
(Or maybe it's $c f(z)$, or $c/f(z)$ for some constant $c$; it's impossible to tell, because the plots look basically the same with the chosen coloring.)

The plot is over the square with corners at $z = \pm 2 \pm 2i$ in the complex plane $\mathbf{C}$.

Here's my reconstruction.
The colors (which aren't quite the same in my version) are based on the argument of $f(z)$, with each angle being assigned a color from a color wheel. Also, half of the shading is constructed from the argument, in such a way that each step corresponds to a change of $\pi/6$ in the argument (so 12 step for a whole lap).

[image: arg colors]

[image: arg shades]

And the other half of the shading is based on the absolute value of $f(z)$, with a logarithmic scale such that each step corresponds to a doubling of $|f(z)|$:

[image: abs shades]

And when you stack these three pictures on top of each other, you get the final image:

[image: combined]

Comment: Very nice and instructive reconstruction. (+1)

Comment: Yes, That's amazing!

Comment: Really nice detective work!

Comment: Thanks everybody for the kind words! To be honest, it wasn't that difficult for me, since I've been playing around with images like these for a long time (and I even made some [web pages](https://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex/) about it once upon a time). The colors and the abs-shading were very familiar; the only new part for me was the arg-shading, but since those curves were orthogonal to the abs-shading, it wasn't too hard to figure out.